# The frontier_exploration demo fails quickly because the robot can't move

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instructions given at the frontier_exploration wiki page:

http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration#For_running_a_demo

```
roslaunch navigation_stage move_base_gmapping_5cm.launch
roslaunch navigation_stage move_base.xml
roslaunch frontier_exploration global_map.launch
```

After I specified an exploration region in rviz, the robot will start exploring but soon it will stops.

From the rviz and stage, I observed that the robot most of the times got stuck to some obstacle and failed to recover, but sometimes it was in a open space, not close to any obstacle, and still couldn't move.

In the frontier_exploration terminal, I always saw an error message:

```
[ERROR] [1491936923.242211778, 124.600000000]: Failed to move
```

In the move_base terminal, I saw a related error message when the robot got stuck:

```
[ERROR] [1491936126.596561945, 221.100000000]: Aborting because a valid plan could not be found. Even after executing all recovery behaviors
```

Has anyone else encounter a similar issue?  Do I need to change some configurations/parameters of move_base and exploration_frontier? Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259016/the-frontier_exploration-demo-fails-quickly-because-the-robot-can%27t-move./) by [renweiros](https://answers.ros.org/users/29408/renweiros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found one possible cause for this issue. The footprint config in navigation_stage/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml doesn't match the sample config in frontier_exploration/launch/global_map.launch.

The footprint config in costmap_common_params.yaml:

```
#The footprint of the robot and associated padding
footprint: [[-0.325, -0.325], [-0.325, 0.325], [0.325, 0.325], [0.46, 0.0], [0.325, -0.325]]
footprint_padding: 0.01
```

The footprint config in global_map.launch:

```
footprint: [[0.1, 0.0], [0.0, 0.1], [-0.1, 0.0], [0.0, -0.1]]
robot_radius: 0.10
```

I tried changing the one in global_map.launch to match the one in costmap_common_params.yaml and started getting better results, i.e., the exploration won't fail quickly. But the exploration will often fail because the robot can't move, especially when it tries exploring a relatively large unknown area. Does anyone have any suggestion? Many thanks in advance.

---

Originally posted by [renweiros](https://answers.ros.org/users/29408/renweiros/) with karma: 36 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0